# How can I know who created this VMware snapshot?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, log-files, snapshot

Someone made a snapshot of a production VM (vSphere 5.1) a month ago. The snapshot is still there. Apparently this person doesn't know that snapshots are not backup operation...

I would like to find out in the logs who created it but the "Tasks & Events" in vCenter don't allow to go back far enough (I have already change the vSphere client setting > List > Tasks and Events > Page Size to 1000).

Where can I find more logs about the snapshots operations?

Comment: If you have the licence for it then try to use VMware Log Insight in the future, it's ideal for this kind of thing.

Comment: Can you tell us which version of ESXi, or vCenter Server are you using ?

Comment: @Chopper3 unfortunetly, I don't think we have the licence for it but I will definitly check on that.

Comment: @Tolsadus I already have indicated it in my question. We run vSphere 5.1.

Comment: Maybe send an email to your team asking who created it?

Comment: Why are you still on 5.1!!!

Comment: Because there are 6000 VM on it and that it takes time for my client to migrate (to decide to migrate aswell in fact...).